# Maven build failure when trying to create runnable JAR [Failed to create assembly: Error adding file-set]

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, maven-plugin, mssql-jdbc

I have written a code to connect to a database using jdbc, I am using **openJDK11.0.2** and **mssql JDBC driver 8.4.0 x64**.

The connection type is windows authentication and below is the dependency that I have used

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> 
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I did a MAVEN BUILD, the build succeeded and I executed the JAR using **java -jar testJava.jar**
The code ran perfectly and what query i was trying to execute, it got executed.

But I have to ship that JAR to customer, they will execute the JAR at their end, so I tried executing my JAR on a system that was of my friend's, it errored out saying `mssql_jdbc_auth.dll` was missing

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication
```

As a work around, I can make my jar work if i paste **mssql_jdbc_auth.dll** in jdk_/bin/, it is working, but this is not efficient.

I want to ship and point this DLL in my jar using code or some other way, so I looked for maven dependency for this DLL,

I found one

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>mssql-jdbc_auth</artifactId>
       <version>8.4.0.x64</version>
       <type>dll</type>
   </dependency>
```

When I saved my pom.xml, the dependency was downloaded in **.m2** folder, then I tried to maven build my project but it threw me an error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project egain-identity-management-tool: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file-set for 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc_auth:dll:8.4.0.x64' to archive: Error adding archived file-set. PlexusIoResourceCollection not found for: C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc_auth\8.4.0.x64\mssql-jdbc_auth-8.4.0.x64.dll: No such archiver: 'dll'.
```

Basically it was saying DLL was not found even though it was present.

Is it because I am using openJDK11? I just need to ship a JAR that executes a JDBC operation on someone elses computer without moving any file or any manual arrangements.

Please suggest an approach.

//UPDATE

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.testJava.demoProj.ConsoleTool</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

//THIS IS my POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.demo.export</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo-management-tool</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>demo-management-tool</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <!-- <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties> -->
  <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
         <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
         <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
         <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
         <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
         <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>args4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.egain.reporting</groupId>
        <artifactId>egain-reporting-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> 
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>mssql-jdbc_auth</artifactId>
       <version>8.4.0.x64</version>
       <type>dll</type>
   </dependency>    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.testJava.demoProj.ConsoleTool</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repo</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: First show the pom file where you have configured maven-assembly-plugin and more important upgrade your maven-assembly-plugin to the most recent... ..

Comment: okay I am updating in question...

Comment: Question/ updated

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated the question and attached my POM inside it, can you please tell me, I am new with maven. pardon if I am doing soemthing wrong.

Comment: You have to add a version tag to the maven-assembly-plugin are where you define the version of maven-assembly-plugin which can be looked up here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/  furthermore your are mixing different logging framework versions log4j:log4j and org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core ... Apart from that I'm asking why do you use a dll as a dependency in a Java project?

Comment: I do not understand why I need to use a version tag? also, I am using mssql_jdbc driver to create a "windows type of auth" to Database and then create a runnable JAR and export it to other people. The jar is working fine on my system, if I am giving my jar to others, they are getting sql_jdbc_auth.dll missing (which is needed), if i put that DLL in their jdk/bin folder it is working fine, but I dont want to manually do anything, so i want my jar to be independent

Comment: @khmarbaise please suggest

Comment: You have to use the version tag to define the version of maven-assembly-plugin. The DLL needs to be loaded via LoadLibrary as far as I know...really you need to copy into JDK/bin directory? If your jar should be independent then you should prevent using DLL cause they are explicitly bound to Windows only...

Comment: JDBC is dependent on sql_jdbc_auth.dll (if we want to run the JAR on the system on which it was not developed).

Comment: I will try your approach, however I am going nuts to get a perfect solution

Comment: Got the same problem. I've opened an issue here (https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1439)

Comment: @Bahaa Thank you! I will keep a watch closey! Thank you again!